# What are the chances of seeing Minceraft instead of Minecraft on the main menu?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know it exists. I just don't know when it happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the Minecraft wiki at https://minecraft.wiki/w/Menu_screen#Minceraft:

> There is a 0.01% chance that the title screen will display "Minceraft" instead of "Minecraft".